# Влияние вызовов OnPropertyChanged("propertyName") на производительность WPF-приложения

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

Изучаю WPF и, соответственно, паттерн MVVM.

Сейчас пишу программу в качестве тренировки. Программа берет данные из выбранного пользователем файла, преобразует их и выводит в `DataTable`. Чтобы очистить `DataTable` я присваиваю свойству, к которому привязан `ItemsSource` таблицы, `null` и вызываю `OnPropertyChanged`.

Так вот вопрос, можно ли часто вызывать этот метод как он повлияет на производительность? Например, у меня 5 разных таблиц и при обработке каждго файла их нужно очистить от результатов предыдущего файла. Как я сказал, я очищаю путем присвоения `null` свойству.

Может быть есть другой способ обновления содержимого `DataTable` (**с учетом паттерна MVVM**)?

Comment: А вы видите проседание производительности? Один OnPropertyChanged на таблицу — это _очень_ мало.

Comment: @VladD, еще раз поясню: я в команде кнопки для 5 таблиц по два раза вызываю OnPropertyChanged. Первый раз для очистки таблиц от предыдущих данных и второй для заполнения новыми. Нет, просадки производительности не заметил, однако, волнует вопрос правильно ли я делаю очистку? И вызовет ли падение производительности, если я буду выполнять аналогичные действия для 15 таблиц, например?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Сама по себе отправки события `PropertyChanged` проблемы не представляет. До тех пор, пока вы не отправляете эти события сотнями за раз, просадки производительности ждать не следует: отправка десятка сообщений и обновление десятка привязок — быстрый процесс.

Гораздо больше времени отнимает полная перерисовка таблицы: ведь для отрисовки *каждого* из элементов необходимо получить данные из многих привязок, а количество этих элементов равно количеству строк таблицы! Но это не проблема `NotifyPropertyChanged` как такового, это проблема вашего дизайна программы. (Например, возможно, вам нужен виртуальный список (`VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizing="True"`).) А может быть это и не будет проблемой, ничего нельзя сказать без профилирования.

Поэтому:

- Не заморачивайтесь с отправкой пары несчастных `PropertyChanged`-нотификаций.
- Но смотрите, не приходит ли случайно огромное количество данных «одним куском» в UI.
- Профилируйте, профилируйте и ещё раз профилируйте.